# How to send a URL to an Angular project with route params?

Tags: angular, email, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a small application to register users. To do it, I send a confirmation email to the registered email, example: hello@world.com

The problem is that the Confirmation URL contains a token in URL Params, example: `domain.net/#/reset-password/lajcNE9kasmlmkdas4359301fasldkm`

When I get the email and then click over the link, my Angular app loads without params.

I already tried to do it with query params just like this:
`domain.net/#/reset-password?token=lajcNE9kasmlmkdas4359301fasldkm`

And still not works

I inject the `ActivatedRoute` from @angular/router in the component constructor

```js
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
}
```

This is the code I'm using to get the route `params`.

```js
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['token']) {
    }
})
```

I expect to get the token from the URL, but the token is null, and the URL in the browser is just `domain.net/#/` without the `params` present in the link sent to the email.

Comment: Can you please inspect and check the link you are clicking in the email that it contains the actual URL that you want or not..?

Answer (score 1):

You can make own custom url serializer by implementing the UrlSerializer class.

Custom Url Serializer

Create a custom url serializer like this:

```
class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    // Custom code here
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    // Custom code here
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to provide the CustomUrlSerializer in place of the UrlSerializer, which you can place in the AppModule providers array after importing both serializers.

providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer },
    ...
]
Now, when you call router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl, it will use your custom serializer for parsing and serializing.